# hash salt complexity

Tags: php, security, hash, salt

Is there any benefit to using:

```
sha1($long_unpredictable_randomly_generated_salt.$password.$global_salt)
```

over

```
sha1(sha1($username).$password.$global_salt)
```

The unique salt is obviously stored in the database, while the global salt is in a configuration file on the server.

I know the purpsoe of a salt is just to be unique, and prevent pre-calculated hash tables.. so I see no reason the long hash generated by `sha1($username)` is not good enough.. but as security is very important, I thought i'd ask for informative advice here from somebody who may know better :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disadvantage is that the username is mostly known, so when someone knows this 'formula' you made up, he can just calculate `sha1(user_to_hack)` and this part won't have any additional benefit. In fact, it won't matter much if you use `sha1(username)` or just `username` in this case.

In the other case, you're using a value that is not exposed, so even when someone knows your formula (which everybody knows now), he'll still needs the value of that unique salt too before it's any use to them, so they'll need to get to your database. I assume you're making up a unique salt for each user?

You'll probably need to get data anyway, so the unique salt is probably faster too, because you won't need to calculate the hash over username.

But anyway, both are pretty safe, *but only if* you implement the actual login procedure well. I wouldn't worry about which one to use right now.

Comment: I think the difference between username and sha1(username) is important in the event that BOTH server and database were hacked.

For example, if a rainbow table for all character combinations upto a length of 15 were generated (with the global salt appended), it's possible this would solve all hashes where the sum length of username+password is 15 or less. If however I use sha1(username), this will not work, they'd have to generate a rainbow table for all combinations upto a length of around 30+ (taking SIGNIFICANTLY longeR)

Comment: It's actually fairly common to save the salt in the database with the password, using the salt as a hedge against lookup tables rather than as extra bits of entropy. Personally, I'd consider a statically saved hash to be as much as public knowledge and not rely on it for entropy anyway...

Comment: Hash of a username is not really random, unless username is secret.

Comment: Joseph, I agree. Can you please review my comment above about the merits of sha1(username) over only username, is it correct?

Comment: @Sil: No, I don't believe there's any real point.  Anyone wanting to attack "Software Monkey" can just as easily build a pre-computation table for sha1("Software Monkey").

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers. I'm going to go ahead and use randomly generate salts, just for peace of mind :-) I'm also going to use key strengthening.

Comment: @sil don't reinvent the wheel. adding complexity increases chances for bugs. Just use hash($randomSalt . $password). It's a proven scheme.

Comment: @sil if you want to increase security, use a better hashing algorithm than sha1: Choose Sha256 or bCrypt-hash.